# Why am I getting an `AttributeError`: “'float' object has no attribute 'lower'” in this code?

Tags: python

I applied lowercase on the dataset like this. I don’t think the problem is caused by this, but what is the real problem?

Why am I getting `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'lower'` here?

```py
film_yorumları["text"] = film_yorumları["text"].str.lower()
```

Full code:

```py
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer

yorumlar=film_yorumları_temiz['text'].values.tolist()
puanlar=film_yorumları_temiz['tag'].values.tolist()

tokenizer_object=Tokenizer()
tokenizer_object.fit_on_texts(yorumlar)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

max_length=max([len(s.split()) for s in yorumlar])

print(max_length) #76

vocab_size = len(tokenizer_object.word_index) +1

#print(vocab_size) #21888

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(yorumlar,puanlar,test_size=0.1)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

x_train_token = tokenizer_object.texts_to_sequences(x_train)
x_test_token = tokenizer_object.texts_to_sequences(x_test)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

x_train_pad = pad_sequences(x_train_token,maxlen=max_length,padding='post')
x_test_pad = pad_sequences(x_test_token,maxlen=max_length,padding='post')
```

Comment: Where does that line occur in your code? What is `film_yorumları`? Do you understand what the error message is telling you?

Comment: ı found answer of this question :).
I had just punctuation text in my line before preprocessing. Then ı applied remove punctuations.
That's why,that line has become a blank line and  ı saw this error. I removed isnull() rows.Problem is solved.
Please warn me if my opinion on this is wrong. If not, I hope it helps others.

Comment: @user4642212 Hello. I've seen your answer now.thank you very much for your return.
In my dataset, there are only movie reviews and their tags, 0 and 1. I got this error when I ran the lines of code I added above. But I think I just found the problem. Can you please read my solution method. I am not sure if it is the right approach?

Comment: There is no answer of mine. Not sure what you’re referring to.

Comment: @user4642212 My English is not enough.

I guess so I could not explain the my solution method well.
sorry for this

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it a string.

```
film_yorumları["text"] = str(film_yorumları["text"]).lower()
```

Comment: Before seeing your message, I found a solution like this. Is it the right approach for you?And thank you very much for your return.

Comment: It is yes, because the str() is a Python function that converts to type str. Then you call the method lower() that is available for type str.

Comment: Thank you again :)